# How can I group by elements in a column in pandas?

Tags: pandas, data-cleaning

I have a dataset that looks like this:

[image]

I need to transform it so it looks like this:

[image]

Meaning I need to show the balance by balance groups and time gaps.

Now the time gaps are elements of a column. I tried to use the following;

```
b = a.pivot_table(values='GAP', index=a.index, columns='BALANCE_GROUP', aggfunc='first')
```

With different parameters but it outputs something really weird. I also tried to use the groupby function which works fine, but it won't allow me to set the elements in the gap column as seperate columns...

```
b = a.groupby(['BALANCE_GROUP','GAP']).sum()
```

and I got something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you need, I think it is this:

```
b = a.pivot_table(values='TOTAL_BALANCE_EUR', index=['NSFR_GROUP', 'BALANCE_GROUP'], columns='GAP', aggfunc='sum')
b
```

It's easier for others to help you if you make the data available to others. Just make a tiny dataframe with 10 rows for instance. Also, you can make the code a bit easier to read by enclosing it in three backticks: ``` or using the code sample button when you write your post.

Comment: AMAZING!!! THANK YOU!